# MVC HTTP POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm having a problem displaying the data from the Get Request to the MVC Controller. I want to get my data from Kanbanize API and display it on my local app. I'm getting Status 200 OK, but when I want to add it in my controller and view something is messing up and I can't understand what.

This is my Get Request with Status Code 200 OK:

```
            List<Board> boards = null;

            string response = string.Empty;
            var url = "https://<subdomain>.kanbanize.com/api/v2/boards/4";

            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.Method = "GET";
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("apikey", "");
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();                
            }

            httpResponse.Close();
            boards = Deserialize<List<Board>>(response);

            return View(boards);
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonData)
        {
            JsonSerializer json = new JsonSerializer();
            return json.Deserialize<T>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonData)));
        }
```

From here I'm getting the info that I want to display, but after that in the controller everything is getting really messy.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and how is the proper way to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define `messy`? How it is different from your expectations?

Comment: "something is messing up" isn't an error message or clear description of an issue, and isn't a fixable problem. Try to stick to specific technical information please.

Comment: In my controller, I'm adding the HttpGet request and I'm creating ViewModel and View, after that I'm creating the HttpPost request but when I want to add something in the board I'm getting error that my request in Unauthorized

Comment: Please tell us the exact error message and the line on which it occurs. Like I said, be **specific**. Your question has "edit" button you can use to update it.

Comment: In my controller, I'm adding the HttpGet request and I'm creating ViewModel and View, after that I'm creating the HttpPost request but when I want to add something in the board I'm getting error JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. Or WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Check the json content received from the server, it's not in the format you're expecting

Answer (score 1):

The response to `https://<subdomain>.kanbanize.com/api/v2/boards/4` returns a single board detail and not a list.

Instead of declaring a list of Board, declare a single instance and try again please.